# Bootstrap grid: unexpected result with divs layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">*some content*</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">*some content*</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">*some content*</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">*some content*</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">*some content*</div>
</div>
```

I would expect 1 row of 3 divs and second row with 2 divs.

The result is:
[image]

What can cause that to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use another classes defined in bootstrap like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-content">
                <div class="col-sm-4">*some content*</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">*some content*</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">*some content*</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">*some content*</div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">*some content*</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

That should help you format positions of your `<div>` tags.
Before you can use those classes, it is important define how many `col-sm-*` you gonna need.
You can use `class="col-sm-offset-4"`as well inside a `<div>` to "skip" some cols defined and make the second line more properly adjusted in your browser.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for answering. Everything is great part of the fact that the number of col-sm-* is unknown, can be 3 or 15. you think your solution still fits?

Answer (score 0):

How about using row structure in the default way:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">*some content*</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">*some content*</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">*some content*</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-6">*some content*</div>
     <div class="col-sm-6">*some content*</div>
</div>
```

in the [standard bootstrap grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) you would also set an outside `container` wrapping everything up, check out the documentation !

Comment: look into flexbox  , it's probably more suited into what you have to do